# How do I open a Telegram chat from my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am working on a flutter app that has a 'Contact me' section. I have already provided a direct `mailto` link in the app using the `url_launcher` plugin.

Now I plan to open a Telegram chat with my telegram account in the user's phone. How do I do it?

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `url_launcher`

here is the code

```dart
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void launchTelegram() async{
String url =
        "https://telegram.me/<telegram_username>";
    print("launchingUrl: $url");
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url, 
      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
    }

}
```

Comment: in new version used this method_______________
 // final Uri _url = Uri.parse(link.url);_______________
 // if (!await launchUrl(_url)) throw 'Could not launch $_url';_______________
its NOT work .
_____________________________________________
so we should use old deprecated methods (canLaunch,launch)