# Flutter html: how to get the document of a new tab

Tags: flutter

I am trying to open telegram in a new tab using flutter. Once telegram is open, I want it to search in the chats using a given input e.g. look for the chats containing `cats`. When using `window.open`, it returns a `WindowBase` instance, which has no `document` attribute. I need that attribute in order to execute `querySelector`.

How can I get the document of the new tab?

Comment: [Does that help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68511866/14945696)

Comment: Can I use that to perform js actions on the newly opened web page?